# Post values from android sqlite3 to sql database to have Sync operation

Tags: php, android, json, http-post

I am trying to upload values from an android sqlite3 database to a mysql database on my server. I have been successful in posting values from a single JSON object that I create. However, when I'm trying to sync values from my sqlite3 database, mysql database on server is not getting updated. Here is my php code on the server.

```
<?php  
mysql_connect('localhost','sapeksha_me','getmein'); 

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);

mysql_select_db("sapeksha_locationdata");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO location (MobileID, Latitude, Longitude, Speed, Acceleration, Time, Date, Sync) VALUES ('".$obj->{'MobileID'}."', '".$obj->{'Latitude'}."', '".$obj->{'Longitude'}."', '".$obj->{'Speed'}."', '".$obj->{'Acceleration'}."', '".$obj->{'Time'}."', '".$obj->{'Date'}."', '".$obj->{'Sync'}."')");

?>
```

And here is the code snippet for posting the content from my sqlite3 database to the server.

```
        SQLiteDatabase db = databasehelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

            if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Sync")).equals("yes") ) {

                String mob = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MobileID"));
                String lat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Latitude"));
                String lng = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Longitude"));
                String speed = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Speed"));
                String acc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Acceleration"));
                String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Date"));
                String time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Time"));
                String update = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Sync"));

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    json.put("MobileID", mob);
                    json.put("Latitude", lat);
                    json.put("Longitude", lng);
                    json.put("Speed", speed);
                    json.put("Acceleration", acc);
                    json.put("Time", time);
                    json.put("Date", date);
                    json.put("Sync", update);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    receive = HttpPostExample.SendJsonUpdate(json, Sync_URL);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(context,  receive,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            cursor.moveToNext();    
        }
        cursor.close();
```

The code snippet using HttpPost..

```
public static String SendJsonUpdate(JSONObject json, String URL) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {


    try {
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);


        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);

        post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
        post.setHeader("json", json.toString());
        StringEntity se;
        se = new StringEntity(json.toString());

        post.setEntity(se);
        post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        post.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) client.execute(post);
        Log.i(TAG, "HTTPResponse received in [" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-t) + "ms]");

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if(entity != null) {

            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
            if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
            }

            String resultString = convertStreamToString(instream);
            instream.close();

            Log.i("Read from server", resultString);

            return resultString;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}
```

Logcat is showing the "HttpResponse received in []" statements, yet the database on the server is not getting updated. I have not still gained experience in android development and php/sql coding. The code might not be the best way of doing it but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there anything in the server logs about the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your auto-commit turned on?

```
mysql_query('SET AUTOCOMMIT=1');
```

If not, wrap your statements in

```
mysql_query('START TRANSACTION');
<your queries>
mysql_query('COMMIT');
```

Comment: I have never used Transaction and Commit statements. But isn't it unnecessary when I have just one query statement?

Comment: Now, I included the 'Start Transaction' and 'Commit' commands and it works now. Thank you! However, can anyone explain why I need to have them even though I had only statement?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's one or multiple. If auto-commit is not true and you dont issue a manual commit, nothing gets written to the database.